# Push to this screen and pop all the screens between them

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

**Scenario:**

```
currently i am on Screen1() then I goto Screen2() and then I goto Screen3().
```

Now I `want to go from Screen3()  to --> Screen1()` and pop all the screens inbetween these two screens .

Please guide me

I tried the `pushAndRemoveUntil` but this pops all the screens not the inbetween screens.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
Navigator.of(context).popUntil((route) => route.settings.name == "/Screen1");
```

Comment: yes this works but here i am not using the named routing like this screen "/Screen1". Can you tell me other way. Here I pushed all the screens like Navigator.of(context).push(
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (c) =>
                              Screen3()),

Comment: If no name is defined, the default one is `/PageClassName`

Comment: not working. because ModalRoute.of(context).settings.name gives null instead of giving the name of screen.

Comment: Who told you ModalRoute.of(context) ?

Comment: i checked this because it gives the current screen on the stack but it gives me null

Comment: `route.settings.name`. Never told you `Modal.of(context).settings.name`

Comment: but I have test your code. still not working

Answer (score 0):

you can use pushReplacement when you go from screen 1 to screen 2 and use it again when you go from screen 2 to screen 3
if you want to add the back button add it manuallyly

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
if(Navigator.of(context).canPop()) {
  Navigator.of(context).pop() ;
}
```

Put it in a while loop to recursively pop till the start or the logic you intend to use.